# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (on video pause function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to pause a videos whith jQuery Object and have been getting an error that says:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Heres de code:

```
    function daVideos(myVideo, arrPause, _src)
    {
         $player = myVideo.get(0);
         $player.attr('src', _src);
         $player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event)
         {
              var isPause = false;

              for(var i=0; i<arrPause.lenght; i++)
              {

                    if($player.currentTime >= arrPause[i]  && !isPause)
                    {
                        isPause = true;
                        $player.pause();

                    }
              } 
         });
    }

     var arr1 = [2,4];
     daVideos($("#video"), arr1, "video/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4");
```

Any body can help me saying what im doing wrong???

Comment: First you create a reference to DOM element `$player = myVideo.get(0);`, then you try to call a jQuery function of that element...

Comment: DOM element !== jQuery object, they have different APIs. If you try to use one as the other, you get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$player = myVideo.get(0);
$player.attr('src', _src);
$player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event)
```

Let's think about these lines. To start with, we have a jQuery object (`myVideo`). We then get the native DOM object with `get(0)` (`$player`). We then attempt to call a jQuery function (`attr`) on the native DOM object (this is where the error occurs, because a native DOM object doesn't have an `attr` function).  We then try to add an event using the native `addEventListener` system.

This all seems a bit complicated and a bit confused. The simple solution is simply to use jQuery throughout:

```
var $player = myVideo.get(0); // keep for later, note we're using var
myVideo.attr('src', _src);
myVideo.on('timeupdate', function(event)
```

The other alternative is simply to use the DOM:

```
var $player = myVideo.get(0); // note that we're using var again
$player.src = _src;
$player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$player = myVideo.get(0);
```

gives the real element, not the jQuery wrapper. And `attr` is a method of jQuery wrapper objects.

If you want to get the first element of the jQuery object, but still have it wrapped in jQuery, you can use `eq` instead of `get`:

```
$player = myVideo.eq(0);
$player.attr('src', _src);
```

Note then you must get the real element, or use `on` instead of `addEventListener`.

Alternatively, you can do it the vanilla-js way:

```
$player = myVideo.get(0);
$player.setAttribute('src', _src);
```